# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int' in SVM

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I was trying to test the effect of different parameters `C` in `LinearSVC` and plot it using the following code:

```py
scores=[]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(SNPs_df, SNPs_class, test_size=0.33)
for this_C in zip([0.00001, 100]):
    model = LinearSVC(C=this_C)
    model.fit(X_train,y_train)
    scores.append(model.score(X_test, y_test))

plt.plot(this_C, np.mean(scores), 'bo')
plt.xlabel('Training set proportion (%)')
plt.ylabel('accuracy');
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'
```

Comment: Your processed data is mixed with `int and tuple`.

Comment: so what can i do? @ashraful

Comment: You should ensure in feature column contains only `int` values.

Comment: @NaghmeVahabi Did you solve the issue? I might be able to help if you show a sample of your data

Comment: thanks for your help. I solved it by changing this part of the code: " zip([0.00001, 100])".